# SQL-Server update column allowing fields not to be edited

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Instead of making a ton of different editing methods for a user in my database, I'd like to make just one, that takes everything, but also allows the client to leave fields blank.
If a field is left blank, nothing is edited, and the value is kept as it is.

My script looks like this so far, but as you can probably guess, it doesn't work:

```
USE [Library]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[editUserByID]
    @ID INT,
    @username VARCHAR(255),
    @password VARCHAR(255),
    @mail VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.users 
    SET dbo.users.username = @username, 
        dbo.users.password = @password, 
        dbo.users.mail = @mail
    WHERE dbo.users.ID = @ID
END
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using COALESCE?

Comment: I tried something like this:

UPDATE dbo.users 
 SET dbo.users.username = COALESCE(@username,username), 
 WHERE dbo.users.ID = @ID

But it just gave me another error

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure dbo.editUserByID, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
Procedure or function 'editUserByID' expects parameter '@password', which was not supplied.

(1 row affected)

Comment: Supply default if you want arguments to be optional.

Comment: Default as in; I set the values to a default, or the original value (prior to edit) becomes the default, and thus the field is left unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COALESCE()` is the right approach, you just need to default the parameters to `NULL` so the proc doesn't fail if they aren't supplied.

```
USE [Library]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[editUserByID]
    @ID INT,
    @username VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @password VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @mail VARCHAR(255) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.users 
    SET username = COALESCE(@username, username), 
        password = COALESCE(@password,password), 
        mail = COALESCE(@mail, mail)
    WHERE dbo.users.ID = @ID
END
```

I assume `@ID` will never be `NULL`, you can setup the defaults however works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

COALESCE is the way to go, just set your variables to null.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if a passed argument is `null`, and if it is, just return the original field's value. Using `coalesce` would be a relatively elegant way of achieving this:

```
UPDATE dbo.users 
SET    dbo.users.username = COALESCE(@username, dbo.users.username),
       dbo.users.password = COALESCE(@password, dbo.users.passoerd),
       dbo.users.mail     = COALESCE(@mail, dbo.user.mail)
WHERE  dbo.users.ID = @ID
```

Comment: Already tried that, though. It just gives the error: 

Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure dbo.editUserByID, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2] Procedure or function 'editUserByID' expects parameter '@password', which was not supplied. (1 row affected) –

Comment: Isn't that exactly what to OP did?

Comment: @Sam_Francis_Baker MySQL doesn't have default values for parameters. You still need to pass `null`s to the fields you don't want to update.

Comment: Wouldn't that just change the value to null, though? I want the fields that aren't edited to stay unchanged when the client launches the method

Comment: @Sam_Francis_Baker no - if, e.g., `@username` is `null`, the `coalesce` expression would return the value of the `username` column, and thus "update it to itself", leaving it unchanged.

Comment: @Murerinik Jusst out of curiosity, since ive tried running OPs code with COALESCE and get the exact same error. How would you achive what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

You're just rebuilding `UPDATE`. Don't bother with the function. There's no point. Just use `UPDATE` directly.

To prevent someone from modifying the `ID` column, you can [block updates to it specifically](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24735/23369):

```
DENY UPDATE ON dbo.Person (Age, Salary) TO SampleRole;
```